# nuxt link problem when routing from base.com/some/other

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

when I click on navigation link in a page like "base.com/some/other"
it just changes the last part instead of going to base.com/wanted it goes to base.com/some/wanted
is there a way to fix this

```
<nuxt-link to="about">about</nuxt-link> | <nuxt-link to="contact">contact</nuxt-link> | <nuxt-link to="go">Go</nuxt-link>
```

Comment: No one else has this problem?

Comment: My bad not using / causes this.